# I moved root partition by error

Tags: centos, root, vps, move

I'm on a VPS with CentOS 6.5

I was trying to install ASSP so by error i did this command

```
mv -f /* /usr/share/assp
```

and then I can't do anything

when I try something like:

```
[/]# dir
-bash: /bin/ls: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
/usr/share/assp/bin/mv -f /usr/share/assp/* /
```

to move the data back.

In case that fails due to missing libraries, you could try to set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to the appropriate paths (it should be `/usr/share/assp/lib` or `/usr/share/assp/lib64`) or you could try to use a statically linked `mv` command (eg. the one provided by `busybox`).

You could also try to boot a rescue system image that has the `mv` command and then mount the file systems properly to move the data back.

Comment: Thank you i try to but i get this error -bash: /usr/share/assp/bin/mv: /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2: bad ELF interpreter: